Power BI Dax want particular date same as date filter
=VAR DtSelected=SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[TRNDATE])
Var StrtDate=STARTOFYEAR(Dates[TRNDATE])
Var EndDate=SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[TRNDATE])
Var Result=
Calculate(Sum('WO 3Years'[Written $ TY]),All('WO 3Years'[DATE]),DATESBETWEEN('WO 3Years'[DATE],StrtDate,EndDate))
Return
 Result

Want selected date in written $TY Column, When I run this this is not showing the particular date filter

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Written TY =
VAR DtSelected=SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[TRNDATE])
Var StrtDate=STARTOFYEAR(Dates[TRNDATE])
Var EndDate =  SELECTEDVALUE(Dates[TRNDATE])
Var Result=
Calculate(
Sum('WO 3Years'[Written $ TY]), All('WO 3Years'[DATE]), DATESBETWEEN('WO 3Years'[DATE],StrtDate, EndDate))
Return
Result
I want to print for example, i will select date 14th so this is show me 1-14 in a month
i want the same
